# Overriding a [[noreturn]] virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, noreturn

The `[[noreturn]]` attribute can be applied to functions that are not meant to return.  For example:

```
[[noreturn]] void will_throw() { throw std::runtime_error("bad, bad, bad ...."); }
```

But I've encountered the following situation (no, I didn't design this):

```cpp
class B {
public:
  virtual void f() { throw std::runtime_error(""); }
};

class D : public B {
  void f() override { std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl; }
};
```

I would really like to place the attribute `[[noreturn]]` on the `B::f()` declaration.  But I'm unclear as to what happens to the override in the derived class.  Successfully returning from a `[[noreturn]]` function results in undefined behavior, and I certainly don't want that if an override also inherits the attribute.

**The question:** By overriding `[[noreturn] virtual void B::f()`, do I inherit the `[[noreturn]]` attribute?

I've looked through the C++14 standard, and I'm having trouble determining if attributes are inherited.

Comment: I don't know, just guessing but at the point when you call B->f() the compiler most likely will have no idea what is  the Dynamic  type of B, so i think the compiler will optimise with noreturn. I don't know why this design, if it's because B doesn't have an implementation for this and this throw is a sign of "don't call this, only at derived classes" then sign it with noreturn doesn't make sense to me. (well, the design itself also doesn't make much sense. :D). If you use the static type of D i expect that the compiler won't optimize to noreturn. Again: I just guess it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, neither **[g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18c9dc7b3096c830)**, [**clang**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80707553beb202af) nor [**MSVC**](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) consider the `[[noreturn]]` attribute as inherited

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
public:
  [[noreturn]] virtual void f() { std::cout << "B\n"; throw 0; }
};

struct D : public B {
  void f() override { std::cout << "D\n"; }
};

int main() 
{
    try { B{}.f(); } catch(...) {}
    D{}.f();

    B* d = new D{};
    d->f();
}
```

which prints out "B", "D" and "D" for all three compilers.

Comment: Since returning from a `noreturn` function is UB, what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @dyp returning from `BB{l.f()` gives a warning on clang, so I had expected a warning  for `d.f()` if noreturn had been transitive (evern if UB is ndr)

Answer (score 13):

I have grepped through the standard, and there's no indication that either `[[noreturn]]` specifically, or attributes more generally, are "inherited" by overriding functions.

It's hard to prove a negative, and the standard actually doesn't declare this either way but, since `A::f()` and `B::f()` are still distinct functions and the only behaviour described is defined in terms of functions, I think you're safe to mark `A::f()` as `[[noreturn]]`.

That being said, I can't imagine what useful optimisation the compiler could subsequently perform, given the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: **+1**: Attributes are not inherited since they apply ([standard wording] *"appertains"*) to the entity where they are written. In OPs example `[[noreturn]]` applies to `void B::f ()` - `void D::f ()` is an entirely different entity.

Answer (score 4):

Consider what you are actually saying:

```
class B
{
public:
    [[noreturn]] virtual void f() { throw std::runtime_error(""); }
};
```

Certainly the human reader, and possibly the compiler, would interpret
this as a 'contract', i.e. 
 "`f()` wont return, I promise"

That should then apply to overrides of `f()` too, or else you are breaking the contract.

The standard might be underspecified on this, but even if it works, I would recommend against it based on readability.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that `[[noreturn]` specifies a contract any more than the access specifier of the base class specifies a contract.  Namely, the public/protected/private access of a function override in a derived class is independent of that in the base class.  The clincher for me, however, is related to your last statement.  Since the standard does not specify it, then it falls under unspecified behavior, and I should therefore not depend upon it.

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel The contract is between caller and callee, not between base and derived. Access specifier can be argued to be part of this contract. `public: void f()` is promising that `b->f()` will always be accessible, and that promise will hold true even if `f` is overridden by a private function in `D`. A better argument would be that `[[noreturn]]` is no more a part of the contract than the `=0` of a pure virtual function is.