# Are C++ type-attributes inherited?

Tags: c++, c++11

I think it's not really a duplicate of [Are function attributes inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576298/are-function-attributes-inherited), because I'm wondering about classes, not member functions :

```
struct [[nodiscard]] error {};
struct critical_error : error {};

critical_error foo();

int main() {
   foo(); // no warning.
}
```

It seems that the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute is not inherited here. Is it the same for all type-attributes?

Comment: Did you mean to use one of the classes you defined in the function return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't, as you asserted yourself. The standard is explicit in what exactly is inherited from a base class to a derived one:

> #### 10.6 Derived classes [class.derived]
>
> [2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.derived#2) [...] Unless redeclared in the derived class, members of a base class are also considered to be members of the derived class.
>   Members of a base class other than constructors are said to be *inherited* by the derived class.
>   Constructors of a base class can also be inherited as described in [namespace.udecl].
>   Inherited members can be referred to in expressions in the same manner as other members of the derived class, unless their names are hidden or ambiguous ([class.member.lookup]).

For the sake of completeness: There is also no wording about inheritance in the [specific section about attributes](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr).

Basically: an attribute is not a member of the class or a constructor, so it can't be inherited.