# Is GCC correct to ignore the nodiscard attribute on overridden member functions?

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

Due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576298/are-function-attributes-inherited) question and the answers, it's not 100% clear whether attributes are inherited or not, but probably they're not since it's not stated in the standard. That's why if we have only the declaration marked as `nodiscard` in the base class, and compile using Clang, we only get a warning if we access the object using a "base" pointer.

The problem with the following code is that it does not warn at all when compiling with GCC (versions 8.1 through 11.1). Having `nodiscard` only in the `Child1`, in both classes, or only in `Base`, calling through a `Base` pointer or a `Child1` pointer, all these do not help.

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    [[nodiscard]] 
    virtual int getIdentifier() const = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Base {
public:
    [[nodiscard]]
    int getIdentifier() const override {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<const Child1> p1 { new Child1 };
    p1->getIdentifier();

    std::unique_ptr<const Base> p2 { new Child1 };
    p2->getIdentifier();
}
```

Is this a sort of a bug in GCC (not likely since every single version available in Compiler Explorer, from 8.1 to 11.1, produce the same result), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For me, it seems a GCC bug. Clang works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it seems a bug, because it works on Clang. But this bug needs 2 conditions to trigger:

1. `virtual` method
2. Indirect addressing. In your case, `unique_ptr` does it. If you get a simple instance and call function directly, you will see warning.

But if you need a workaround, you can use another attribute. Here is a small sample:

```
struct A{
    [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
    virtual int foo() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    a.foo();
}
```

This attribute works for both GCC and Clang.

**Another suggestion**: You can use attribute like `[[nodiscard, gnu::warn_unused_result]]`, This will works for all compilers.

Comment: You were faster with your answer, so I'll just add a comment :-) This looks like a [known bug in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97712).